# Mid project finishing basement: should I rip out new framing?

Tags: insulation, basement, framing, moisture

I am learning that the wood framing that has just been installed (glued) in my basement really should have come after putting in continuous foam board insulation against the wall, separating the wood from the exterior (DryLock painted) cinder block. Instead, our plan had been to install 2.5"(R 12.5) unfaced XPS insulation between the new studs. There is an intentional gap between the bottom of the framing and the cement floor. Our goal is to have finished living space at the end of this project.

My question:
Is having the wood framing against the painted cinder block wall going to create moisture buildup in the basement wall through condensation, or is it sufficient at this point to leave the framing as is, glued directly to the painted cinder block, and insulate between the studs?

I don't want to gloss over a problem now and regret it later, if the studs against cinder block is going to create a condensation problem over time.

Still, I don't want to hammer out all of that brand new framing, if the disadvantage of our arrangement is negligible.

Comment: If the block wall is dry I would leave it as it is. I have had 3 homes with basements and one had Sheetrock glued to the walls and it was fine, I only found out about the Sheetrock being glued because I wanted to add outlets.

Answer (score 2):

Your concerns are valid.

If condensate does form, you will also likely have to deal with mold. I would definitely rip it out and add high density foam. Not sure why glue was used, but am guessing that it'd be a lot easier to use Power loads to nail the framing after the insulation is installed.

I treated my basement framing with anti-fungal/anti-mold treatment as an additional precaution.